# Merge Value In The Same Array (Python)?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a short code in Python like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b[0] = 100
print(a)
```

But the result i had is:

```
Output: [100, 2, 3]
```

Someones help me with explaining and how to fix that

Comment: When `b = a`, b and a will point to the same list.

Comment: Sounds like you want to copy your list instead of just reference it (such as you have with `b = a`). You could do `b = list(a)` to create a copy of `a`, so that any changes made to `b` do not affect `a`

Answer (score 1):

In your example, both b and a are referring to the same object. You should make a separate copy if you wish to change each of them independently. There are many ways to do it:

Option 1:

```
def Cloning(li1): 
    li_copy = li1[:] 
    return li_copy 

a = [1, 2, 3,] 
b = Cloning(a) 
b[0] = 100
print("Original List:", a) 
print("After Cloning:", b)
```

2:

```
# Using the in-built function extend() 
def Cloning(li1): 
    li_copy = [] 
    li_copy.extend(li1) 
    return li_copy 
  
# Driver Code 
a = [1, 2, 3] 
b = Cloning(li1) 
b[0] = 100

print("Original List:", a) 
print("After Cloning:", b)
```

Option 3:

```
# Using the in-built function list() 
def Cloning(li1): 
    li_copy = list(li1) 
    return li_copy 



# Driver Code 

a = [1, 2, 3] 
b = Cloning(li1) 
b[0] = 100

print("Original List:", a) 
print("After Cloning:", b)
```

Option 4:

```
# Using list comprehension 
def Cloning(li1): 
    li_copy = [i for i in li1] 
    return li_copy 
  
# Driver Code 
    a = [1, 2, 3] 
    b = Cloning(li1) 
    b[0] = 100
    
    print("Original List:", a) 
    print("After Cloning:", b)
```

Option 5:

```
# Using append() 
def Cloning(li1): 
    li_copy =[] 
    for item in li1: li_copy.append(item) 
    return li_copy 
  
# Driver Code 
        a = [1, 2, 3] 
        b = Cloning(li1) 
        b[0] = 100
        
        print("Original List:", a) 
        print("After Cloning:", b)
```

Option 6:

```
# Using bilt-in method copy() 
def Cloning(li1): 
    li_copy =[] 
    li_copy = li1.copy() 
    return li_copy 
  
# Driver Code 
       a = [1, 2, 3] 
            b = Cloning(li1) 
            b[0] = 100
            
            print("Original List:", a) 
            print("After Cloning:", b)
```

Comment: @LêTríTâm welcome. If it solves your problem please mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

`b=a` is essentially assigning the memory address of `a` to `b` not the value.
If you want the value than do the following:

```py
a = [1,2,3]

b = a.copy()
b[0]=111
print(a,b)
>>>[1, 2, 3] [111, 2, 3]
```

Comment: OK. Let me see. Thank for your comment

Comment: Why are you importing `copy`?

Comment: don't we have to ?\

Comment: Try it without.

Comment: copy in this case is a function defined in the list class (which makes it a method)..every list object will have a .copy() method implicity defined.. there is no need to import a function from a module - in fact, the copy you imported is never actually used

Comment: Removed it. Thanks for the info:)

Answer (score 0):

you have already assigned `b=a`, therefore you are just appending `b[0]=100` to the list of `a`. Do something like this

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.copy()
b[0] = 100
print(a)
print(b)
```

output: `[1, 2, 3]`
`[100, 2, 3]`